# Distance from point to plane for linear plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Seems rather elementary but I have stumbled upon this, what is the shortest distance from $(7, -3)$ to the plane $x = 1$?

Using the formulas I see the plane equation as

$x - 1 = 0$ and the point is $(x_1, y_1) = (7, -3)$ so shouln't the distance be

$d = \frac{|7 - 1|}{\sqrt{1}} = 6$

Comment: but $x=1$ is a straight line

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the shortest distance to the plane?

Comment: @lioness99a, yeah that

Comment: convert $x-1=0$ into the Hessian normalform

Answer (score 1):

Plane: $x-1=0$, where $A=1$, $B=0$, $C=-1$

Point: $(7,-3)$, where $x_0=7$, $y_0=-3$

\begin{align}d&=\frac{|Ax_0+By_0+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\\
&=\frac{|1(7)+0(-3)-1|}{\sqrt{1^2 +0^2}}\\&=6\end{align}

Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

We can draw a graph of this situation:

[image: graph]

For a general line, the shortest distance will fall on the line which is perpendicular to the original line. In this case, the perpendicular line runs horizontally, and therefore we want the line which is horizontal and passes through the point $(7,-3)$: $$y=-3$$

Therefore, we are looking for the distance between the points $(1,-3)$ and $(7,-3)$ which we can see easily is $6$.